# Regex to parse Active Directory string fails

Tags: c#, regex, code-behind

I have this block of code in C# code-behind:

```
string input = "CN=L_WDJACK127_WDC_SSIS_USER_CH,OU=ALOSup,OU=Infra,DC=internal, DC=mycompany,DC=com"
string pattern = @"CN\=(.+)\,";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

When I run this, **match.Groups[1].Value** is equal to

> L_WDJACK127_WDC_SSIS_USER_CH,OU=ALOSup,OU=Infra,DC=internal,
>   DC=mycompany

I need it to be equal to

> L_WDJACK127_WDC_SSIS_USER_CH

Can someone please fix my Regex?

Comment: You don't need a regex for this. Split on commas, split on equal signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Greedy/Lazy quantifier problem:

```
string pattern = @"CN\=(.+?)\,";
```

This resource should help as to why: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Basically, the `.+` tries to match *as many of any character, and at least one of which, as possible before hitting the **last** comma*. By adding a `?` to the end of it (`.+?`) you tell the Regex Engine to match *as many of any, and at least one of which, character as possible before you hit the **first** comma*.

Comment: Thanks!  Worked perfectly!